# python requests image upload fails to drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

```
    import json
    import requests

    user_f = open('categories.json',)
    users = json.load(user_f)


    media_api = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/'

    files=[
        ('category_image', ("Traditional-Art.png", open("Traditional-Art.png",'rb'),'image/jpeg'))
    ]

    json = {
        "category_name": "cat",
        "category_description": "desc",
        "user": 16
    }

    headers = {
                "Accept": 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                "enctype":"multipart/form-data"
            }

    response = requests.request("POST", media_api, headers=headers, data=json, files=files)
    print(response.json())
```

Here, i am trying to upload image to django rest-framework and getting below error

```
`{u'category_image': [u'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.']}`
```

this works when image is jpg format but, not working in png .
Am i missing anything or do i need to modify something ?

Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

what you have done is wrong either you try to send the data as json or as form do something like it may help you.

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
      fields={
           # a file upload field
           'file': ('file.zip', open('file.zip', 'rb'), 'text/plain')
           # plain text fields
           'field0': 'value0', 
           'field1': 'value1',
         }
 )

 response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', 
              data=multipart_data,
              headers={'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type})
```